# Delphi Percorrer os Nós de Um XML (DOM)

Tags: delphi, xml, delphi-5

Tenho o código abaixo, porém não estou conseguindo listar o nome do nó e seu valor. Consigo pesquisar e mostrar o nó principal tipo **[ide]** porém o sub-nó que seria **[cUF] + valor** isso eu não consigo.

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);  
var
    Doc: IXMLDOMDocument;  
    Element: IXMLDOMElement;  
    List: IXMLDOMNodeList;  
    attrib : IXMLDOMNode;  
    Path,ID,title,producer: string;  
    i: integer;  
begin    
    Memo1.Lines.Clear;
    Doc := CoDOMDocument.Create;
    Doc.load(ArquivoXML);
    // Element := Doc.documentElement;
    // List := Element.getElementsByTagName('ide');
    for i := 0 to Doc.selectNodes('//ide').length do
    begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Doc.selectNodes('//ide').item[i].baseName);     // Nó onde está parado
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Doc.selectNodes('//ide').item[i].Get_nodeName); // = basename
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Doc.selectNodes('//ide').item[i].nodeName);     // = basename
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Doc.selectNodes('//ide').item[i].selectSingleNode('cUF').text);   // Pego o Conteúdo do item do Nó
        Memo1.Lines.Add(Doc.selectNodes('//ide').item[i].selectSingleNode('cNF').text);   // Pego o Conteúdo do item do Nó

//        Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(GetNodeInt(attrib,'cNF')));
    end;
end;
```

**Trecho do XML**:

```
[CFe]  
    [infCFe versaoSB="000003" versaoDadosEnt="0.07" versao="0.07"  
    Id="CFeNumero_da_chave"]  
        [ide]  
            [cUF]35[/cUF]  
            [cNF]164796[/cNF]  
            [mod]59[/mod]  
            [nserieSAT]123456789[/nserieSAT]  
            [nCFe]000289[/nCFe]  
            [dEmi]20181029[/dEmi]  
            [hEmi]100256[/hEmi]  
            [cDV]3[/cDV]  
            [tpAmb]2[/tpAmb]  
            [CNPJ]11111111111111[/CNPJ]  
            [signAC]assinatura[/signAC]  
            [assinaturaQRCODE]QRCode[/assinaturaQRCODE]  
            [numeroCaixa]002[/numeroCaixa]  
        [/ide]  
    [/infCFe"  
[/CFe]
```

Comment: Não teria que seguir a mesma lógica da busca por `ide` colocando duas barras antes? Dessa forma: `Doc.selectNodes('//ide').item[i].selectSingleNode('//cUF').text`

Comment: Já fiz. Mas ele não vai para os próximos módulos, precisava por em loop e ir passando Nó a Nó, coisa que não está fazendo. E por algum motivo não consigo pegar o nome do nó.

Comment: Então não entendi sua pergunta, você quer varrer todos os nós do nó `ide`?

Comment: Se possível, adicione na pergunta a saída desejada.

Comment: Isso mesmo, abrir o XML colocar num loop e ir percorrendo os nós. Estou jogando os valores a nivel de teste para um memo, mas vou jogar esses valores para uma tabela... Exemplo preciso percorrer o xml começando o Nó <CFe>, para pegar os sub-nós e seus valores.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente a propriedade `length` do `IXMLDOMNodeList` não esta funcionando corretamente. A solução então foi utilizar a função `nextNode` até que ela retorne `nil`. Após obter o nó é só varrer todos os nós filhos e imprimi-los:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    Doc: IXMLDOMDocument;
    nodes: IXMLDOMNodeList;
    node : IXMLDOMNode;
    i: integer;
begin
    Memo1.Lines.Clear;
    Doc := CoDOMDocument.Create;
    Doc.loadXML(
      '<CFe>                                                                                      ' +
      '    <infCFe versaoSB="000003" versaoDadosEnt="0.07" versao="0.07" Id="CFeNumero_da_chave"> ' +
      '        <ide>                                                                              ' +
      '            <cUF>35</cUF>                                                                  ' +
      '            <cNF>164796</cNF>                                                              ' +
      '            <mod>59</mod>                                                                  ' +
      '            <nserieSAT>123456789</nserieSAT>                                               ' +
      '            <nCFe>000289</nCFe>                                                            ' +
      '            <dEmi>20181029</dEmi>                                                          ' +
      '            <hEmi>100256</hEmi>                                                            ' +
      '            <cDV>3</cDV>                                                                   ' +
      '            <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>                                                               ' +
      '            <CNPJ>11111111111111</CNPJ>                                                    ' +
      '            <signAC>assinatura</signAC>                                                    ' +
      '            <assinaturaQRCODE>QRCode</assinaturaQRCODE>                                    ' +
      '            <numeroCaixa>002</numeroCaixa>                                                 ' +
      '        </ide>                                                                             ' +
      '        <ide>                                                                              ' +
      '            <cUF>36</cUF>                                                                  ' +
      '            <cNF>164797</cNF>                                                              ' +
      '            <mod>60</mod>                                                                  ' +
      '            <nserieSAT>123456790</nserieSAT>                                               ' +
      '            <nCFe>000290</nCFe>                                                            ' +
      '            <dEmi>20181030</dEmi>                                                          ' +
      '            <hEmi>100257</hEmi>                                                            ' +
      '            <cDV>4</cDV>                                                                   ' +
      '            <tpAmb>3</tpAmb>                                                               ' +
      '            <CNPJ>11111111111112</CNPJ>                                                    ' +
      '            <signAC>assinatura1</signAC>                                                   ' +
      '            <assinaturaQRCODE>QRCode1</assinaturaQRCODE>                                   ' +
      '            <numeroCaixa>003</numeroCaixa>                                                 ' +
      '        </ide>                                                                             ' +
      '    </infCFe>                                                                              ' +
      '</CFe>                                                                                     '
    );

    nodes := Doc.getElementsByTagName('ide');

    repeat
      node := nodes.nextNode;

      if (node = nil) then
        Break;

      Memo1.Lines.Add(node.baseName);
      for i := 0 to node.childNodes.length - 1 do
        Memo1.Lines.Add('[' + node.childNodes.item[i].nodeName + '] ' + node.childNodes.item[i].text);
    until (node = nil);
end;
```

O resultado disso foi:

```
ide
[cUF] 35
[cNF] 164796
[mod] 59
[nserieSAT] 123456789
[nCFe] 000289
[dEmi] 20181029
[hEmi] 100256
[cDV] 3
[tpAmb] 2
[CNPJ] 11111111111111
[signAC] assinatura
[assinaturaQRCODE] QRCode
[numeroCaixa] 002
ide
[cUF] 36
[cNF] 164797
[mod] 60
[nserieSAT] 123456790
[nCFe] 000290
[dEmi] 20181030
[hEmi] 100257
[cDV] 4
[tpAmb] 3
[CNPJ] 11111111111112
[signAC] assinatura1
[assinaturaQRCODE] QRCode1
[numeroCaixa] 003
```

Utilizei o seguinte `XML` como exemplo:

```
<CFe>                                                                                      
    <infCFe versaoSB="000003" versaoDadosEnt="0.07" versao="0.07" Id="CFeNumero_da_chave"> 
        <ide>                                                                              
            <cUF>35</cUF>                                                                  
            <cNF>164796</cNF>                                                              
            <mod>59</mod>                                                                  
            <nserieSAT>123456789</nserieSAT>                                               
            <nCFe>000289</nCFe>                                                            
            <dEmi>20181029</dEmi>                                                          
            <hEmi>100256</hEmi>                                                            
            <cDV>3</cDV>                                                                   
            <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>                                                               
            <CNPJ>11111111111111</CNPJ>                                                    
            <signAC>assinatura</signAC>                                                    
            <assinaturaQRCODE>QRCode</assinaturaQRCODE>                                    
            <numeroCaixa>002</numeroCaixa>                                                 
        </ide>                                                                             
        <ide>                                                                              
            <cUF>36</cUF>                                                                  
            <cNF>164797</cNF>                                                              
            <mod>60</mod>                                                                  
            <nserieSAT>123456790</nserieSAT>                                               
            <nCFe>000290</nCFe>                                                            
            <dEmi>20181030</dEmi>                                                          
            <hEmi>100257</hEmi>                                                            
            <cDV>4</cDV>                                                                   
            <tpAmb>3</tpAmb>                                                               
            <CNPJ>11111111111112</CNPJ>                                                    
            <signAC>assinatura1</signAC>                                                   
            <assinaturaQRCODE>QRCode1</assinaturaQRCODE>                                   
            <numeroCaixa>003</numeroCaixa>                                                 
        </ide>                                                                             
    </infCFe>                                                                              
</CFe>
```

Não tenho o Delphi 5 instalado na minha máquina, realizei esses testes no Delphi 2010, mas acredito que não tenha muitas diferenças. Também não foi possível carregar o `XML` com as tags envolvidas por `[]` por substitui por `<>`.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Coloquei colchetes, pois aqui não consigo postar os códigos.

Comment: Beleza. Se a resposta lhe foi útil, dê a ela o devido valor. Aceite-a ou dê um up, ou as duas ações :D

Comment: Estou tentando te pontuar, como faço ?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), nele é explicado como fazer.